# Query list for items based on function result

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Zip` items (`ZipCodes`) which contain the `Location` of each ZCTA (Zip Code Tabulated Area), and there are ~33,000 items in said list at present.

I could include my `Zip` class, but I think the only thing of note is that it contains a `LatLong` item named `Location` which holds the latitude and longitude coordinates. `Haversine()` accepts `LatLong` items and does some magic stuff to return a double.

I'm trying to pull the 5 closest zip codes (with distances) to the one that I provide. This is my current solution (don't mind that I manually added the 5 null KVPs):

```
//don't judge me... I'm still working on a better solution here
private static readonly KeyValuePair<Zip, double> init = new KeyValuePair<Zip, double>(null, 9999);
private static readonly List<KeyValuePair<Zip, double>> workstack = new List<KeyValuePair<Zip, double>>
    {
       init, init, init, init, init
    };

private static KeyValuePair<Zip, double>[] FindClosest(Zip myZip)
{
    var closestList = workstack.ToArray(); //I said don't judge me :(
    //fwiw ^ is actually faster than initializing a new array each cycle

    foreach (var zip in ZipCodes.Where(x => x != myZip))
    {
        //Haversine magic returns distance (double) in km
        var dist = Haversine(myZip.Location, zip.Location);
        //If everything else is smaller, just skip it
        if (closestList.All(x => x.Value < dist)) continue;
        closestList = closestList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToArray();
        closestList[0] = new KeyValuePair<Zip, double>(zip, dist);
    }

    return closestList;
}
```

However, I'd like to write this to be as efficient as possible (I'm not actually 100% sure what the application will be just yet), so (I believe) I'd like to use LINQ.

I altered my code to just grab just the closest zip code, and ReSharper suggested a LINQ query that I was able to work with. I'm not terribly experienced with LINQ, but I was able to restructure it to fit my desired task:

```
//the Skip(1) is to skip the first element, which would be the distance between the zipcode and itself
var closest = ZipCodes.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<Zip, double>
          (x, Haversine(myZip.Location, x.Location))).OrderBy
          (x => x.Value).Skip(1).Take(5).ToArray();
```

I then used the `Stopwatch` to time both functions to process 500 `Zip` items, and found that using the LINQ method took around **11.25s** on average, while my original foreach method took only **8s** on average (LINQ was *slower* by 3.25s per 500 items).

Again, I don't know much about LINQ, but I was always led to believe it was faster. In this case, I can see why it isn't - I'm trying to sort a full list of 33,000 items.

How could I write my query to be more efficient? Or, in general, how could I write a more efficient query to pull a specified number of items from a list, based on their relation to a given item and the rest of the list?

Comment: Is it possible `Haversine()` is taking an excessive amount of time on calculating distance between identical Zip codes? The only significant negative against your Linq code i can see is that it is filtering out starting Zip code at the end, as opposed to do it from the start.

Comment: Also, have you tried to compare performance of your code variants without `Haversine()` calls? I.e. form an array of  `KVP<Zip, double>` first and then stopwatch both expressions.

Comment: I wouldn't think `Skip()` would take a lot of processing time. `Haversine()` shouldn't take any extra time calculating distance regardless of the value, it's just a standard haversine formula. I actually haven't timed it yet though... I'll do that and get back with the results.

Comment: Just tested. I used a `foreach` and `for` loop testing for 0 and nonzero answers, and found that `Haversine()` took about 0.00019s (per 500 calls) on average, regardless of the method used. So that's definitely not slowing anything down.

Comment: This is very odd. Absent of other external factors, I would expect straight Linq query to perform much faster than your code since you're doing additional array resizing operations inside the loop.

Comment: Turns out... I might have timed that a bit wrong.

I timed 500 calls, but not at 33,000 iterations/call. Timing that, I found `Haversine()` to in fact account for a large portion (>90%) of the calculation time. Not sure if I should start a new question or edit this one.

Comment: starting a new one might be easier to get new answers

Comment: You could also first compute the nearest 15 locations using a max norm distance `max(|lat2-lat1|, |lon2-lon1|)` and only then sort the short list using the exact Haversine distance.

Comment: Maybe you should post your Zip class, to see if there's any logical information in there that could help to pre-filter.

Comment: @LutzL I've actually been working on that and it's definitely looking to be the best option right now.

Comment: Marked @tinstaafl's answer as correct as it best addressed the list processing issue I asked in the question. Using a normal distance first, and calculating the Haversine distance at the end, I was able to cut the overall processing time in half right away, and I'm sure there's still room for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're trying to do LINQ might not be the best solution.  However, I think your foreach could be improved a fair bit, by using a SortedList instead of an array:

```
private static SortedList<double, Zip> FindClosest(Zip myZip)
{
    var closestZips = new SortedList<double, Zip>();
    List<Zip> ZipCodes = new List<Zip>();
    foreach (var zip in ZipCodes.Where(x => x != myZip))
    {
        //Haversine magic returns distance (double) in km
        double dist = Haversine(myZip.Location, zip.Location);
        //If everything else is smaller, just skip it
        if (closestZips.Count < 5)
        {
            closestZips.Add(dist, zip);
        }
        else if (dist < closestZips.Keys[4])
        {
            closestZips.RemoveAt(4);
            closestZips.Add(dist, zip);
        }
    }

    return closestZips;
}
```

Realized there was a bug.  got it fixed, but had to reverse keys,values.  So now each distance is the key.

LINQ doesn't really lend itself to short circuiting.  Since you only want a small percentage of the total, LINQ will usually be quite inefficient, since it has to create the whole collection first, then sort it, then select the amount you want.  The main advantage LINQ would have here, I think, is it will be concise and more readable.  Also, I think, with a more efficient foreach loop, the foreach will still come out very favourably.

Edit:  Further optimization

You could try using the Parallel library.  The result weren't 100% consistent but there was a definite speed gain at around 10 - 30%.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private static Object thisLock = new Object();
private static SortedList<double, Zip> FindClosest2(Zip myZip)
{


    var closestZips = new SortedList<double, Zip>();
    Parallel.ForEach(ZipCodes, (zip) =>
     {
         //Haversine magic returns distance (double) in km
         double dist = Haversine(myZip.Location, zip.Location);
         if (closestZips.Count() < 6)
         {
             lock(thisLock)
             {
                 closestZips.Add(dist, zip);
             }

         }
         else if (dist < closestZips.Keys[4])
         {
             lock(thisLock)
             {
                 closestZips.RemoveAt(4);
                 closestZips.Add(dist, zip);
             }

         }
     });

    return closestZips;
}
```

Here's the Haversine I used:

```
public static class Haversine
{
    public static double calculate(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
    {
        var R = 6372.8; // In kilometers
        var dLat = toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        var dLon = toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        lat1 = toRadians(lat1);
        lat2 = toRadians(lat2);

        var a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) + Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2);
        var c = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(a));
        return R * 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(a));
    }
    public static double calculate(Coords a, Coords b)
    {
        return calculate(a.lat, a.lng, b.lat, b.lng);
    }
    public static double toRadians(double angle)
    {
        return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why LINQ might not work best? I'm interested to know. I was thinking about it some and in my head, the LINQ method I wrote would work better than the foreach method if I wanted something like, say, the 50 closest items instead of only 5.

Comment: I added more info for you.

Comment: This method ended up being between 1-2 seconds faster than my original method. It still takes around 6 seconds/500 items, but it's a good start, thanks for the tip with `SortedList<>`!

Comment: Had a further thought for you.  Eliminating the Where extension should help.

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference. I actually initially had the if statement, and later removed it and went with `.Where()` instead. I think the reason it doesn't really matter is the `.Where()` runs once per foreach loop (I think?) but the if statement runs with every iteration (and in this case, `ZipCodes` is roughly 33,000 items in size).

Comment: Had another thought for you.  Parallel library.  This allows for multi threading operations.  Left you an example.

Comment: Added a comment with a recent development.. turns out that most of the calculation time was going to `Haversine()` *facepalm*.

I think that my best option now is to use multithreading to calculate all of the distances, and then sort the final array/list and take 5 items.

Comment: In my tests, which were on the whole 33,00 item list, it seems that the Haversine uses up a large portion of the time, because it's called over 2,500,000 times.  In my tests though it only used up about 60% of the total time.  And the average time was only .04 msec.  I added the function I used, in case that helps.

Comment: `Haversine()` is called 33,000 times per zip code. When I get the closest zip codes for 500 zip codes, it results in 16,500,000 calls. The class that you wrote is essentially identical to mine... and I noticed no performance improvement.

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct as it best addressed the list processing bottleneck I was running into. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, HaverSine() is an expensive function.

In any of the posted solutions you can substitute HaverSine() with something cheaper.  You don't need accurate miles/km to find the nearest. Even for large postal areas, the earth should be flat enough to use a simple Pythagorean distance over the coordinates. Since we only need to compare you don't even have to take the root. And then you'll have to apply HaverSine() to your top 5 for the exact distances.

```
...
var dist = SimpleDistance(myZip.Location, zip.Location); 
...


double  SimpleDistance(Zip a, Zip b)
{
   double dLat = a.Lat - b.Lat;
   double dLon = a.Lon - b.Lon;
   dLon = dLon / 2;  // Lat Lon use different degrees
   return dLon * dLon  + dLat * dLat; 
}
```

But a collection of postal areas should have other means to restrict the search, such as a logical or regional numbering system.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing to optimize the usage of `Haversine()`, instead of calling it again and again. However, I had to take the absolute value of each latitude and longitude, especially since we're in the Western Hemisphere so I would end up with a negative minus a negative which would then be squared and thus make it appear farther away than it actually is. I went with `return Math.Pow(Math.Abs(a.Latitude) - Math.Abs(b.Latitude), 2) +
                          Math.Pow(Math.Abs(a.Longitude) - Math.Abs(b.Longitude), 2);`

Comment: We're micro optimizing now but your Abs() is superfluous at best. And I would use `a*a` any time over `Pow(a,2)`.

Comment: "with a negative minus a negative which would then be squared and thus make it appear farther away ..." - you should really do the math on that. Again.

Comment: Yeah... yeah I probably should :p It's been a long day

Answer (score 0):

HEre's the fully LINQed version.  It'll probably be slower.

```
class ZipDist
{
    public Zip Zip;
    public double Distance;
}

ZipDist[] FindCLosest2(Zip myZip)
{
    return (from zip in ZipCodes
            where zip != myZip
            let dist =  Haversine(myZip.Location, zip.Location)
            orderby dist ascending
            select new ZipDist { Zip = zip, Distance =dist}).Take(5).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I actually went through that iteration as I was trying to find the fastest query (and, now that I look at it, I'll have to edit my LINQ method to account for a thing or two), but it ended up being slower than my current LINQ method and, again, far slower than my foreach loop :/

Answer (score 0):

This should be a bit faster than your method (sorting algorithm a bit more efficient). (I can't say for sure, since I don't have the data structure you use available)

```
public class FixedSortedArray<T>
    where T : new()
{
    T[] _array;

    IComparer<T> _comparer;

    int _unused;

    public FixedSortedArray(int size, IComparer<T> cmp = null)
    {
        _array = new T[size];
        _comparer = cmp ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
        _unused = size;
    }

    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        if (_unused > 0)
        {
            var pos = _unused-1;
            for (int i = _unused; i < _array.Length; ++i)
            {
                var cmp = _comparer.Compare(item, _array[i]);
                if (cmp < 0)
                {
                    _array[i-1] = _array[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    pos = i-1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            _array[pos] = item;
            --_unused;

        }
        else
        {
            var cmp = _comparer.Compare(item, _array[0]);
            if (cmp < 0)
            {
                int pos = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i < _array.Length; ++i)
                {
                    cmp = _comparer.Compare(item, _array[i]);
                    if (cmp < 0)
                    {
                        _array[i - 1] = _array[i];
                        pos = i;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (pos >= 0)
                    _array[pos] = item;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public T[] GetArray()
    {
        return _array;
    }

}

class ZipDist
{
    public Zip Zip;
    public double Distance;
}

class ZipDistCOmparer : IComparer<ZipDist>
{
    public int Compare(ZipDist lhs, ZipDist rhs)
    {
        return lhs.Distance.CompareTo(rhs.Distance);
    }
}
private static ZipDist[] FindClosest(Zip myZip)
{
    var closestList = new FixedSortedArray<ZipDist>(5, new ZipDistCOmparer());

    foreach (var zip in ZipCodes.Where(x => x != myZip))
    {
        //Haversine magic returns distance (double) in km
        var dist = Haversine(myZip.Location, zip.Location);
        closestList.Add(new ZipDist { Zip = zip, Distance = dist});
    }

    return closestList.GetArray();
}

// Stuff I needed to add to get it to compile
public class Zip
{
    public string Location;
}

static public Zip[] ZipCodes;

static double Haversine(string lhs, string rhs) { return 0.0; }
```

Comment: Runs about on par with my original method, and approx. 1 second slower than the SortedList<> method @tinstaafl wrote. Also, not sure if this was intended, but it seems that the array in your method was sorted so that the smallest value was last. Doesn't matter much (just called `Last()` instead of `First()`), but maybe it does to you.

For the record, I got those numbers timing your method `FindClosest(zip).Last().Distance` against tinstaafl's `FindClosest(zip, 5).First().Key` within `foreach (var zip in ZipCodes.Take(500)) { }`.

Comment: Built as a release build and your method was only 0.2s slower on average (4.4s vs 4.2s)