# A More Efficient Haversine Function

Tags: c#, math, optimization, trigonometry

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41515987/query-list-for-items-based-on-function-result), I looked to speed up list selection based on a function result. Now, my bottleneck is the function itself.

It's a basic Haversine function, using the code below:

```
private static double Haversine(double lat1, double lat2, double lon1, double lon2)
{            
    const double r = 6371e3; // meters
    var dlat = (lat2 - lat1)/2;
    var dlon = (lon2 - lon1)/2;

    var q = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dlat), 2) + Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dlon), 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(q), Math.Sqrt(1 - q));

    var d = r * c;
    return d / 1000;
}
```

So... why does it need to be so fast? The issue is that I'm calling it **a lot**. Think north of 16,500,000 times.

Obviously, that's **a lot**. And in my use case I'm passing it objects that it has to get the location data from and then convert Latitude and Longitude to radians, which increases the time further (only by about 15%). I don't know that there's much I can do about that, but I do know that by passing it purely doubles in radians (as above) it takes ~4.5 seconds - which is more than 75% of the processing time in my implementation. The lines assigning values to q and c seems to take up the most time.

As it's being called **a lot**, I'm looking to make it *a bit* faster. I'm open to multithreaded solutions (and am currently working on one myself), but it may be a bit more difficult to implement given the use case in my previous question (linked above).

Comment: The best optimization is to call it less...  A quick look at that other question shows you need a "nearest 5" or something. That makes this a bit of an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Why would converting to or from radians incur such a heavy penalty? It is literally just a single multiplication. Granted it's a floating point operation, but it should still be nowhere near as expensive as those trigonometric functions.

Comment: Also, I'm looking at the definition of the haversine formula on Wikipedia, and there is no mention anywhere of needing to do an Atan. What is the value you are actually trying to get this method to return?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think that's always a good way to look at things though and something I'm often considering. If you can see something immediately that could use improvement I'm open it. In the meantime it's an expensive operation that I'd like to slim down.

Comment: @Abion47 It's just the implementation I used. I think you can do it with or without, the distances come out the same either way. **I'm finding the distance between two Latitude-Longitude pairs.** Converting to radians 16.5 million times costs around 1-1.5 seconds. Realistically I could store all of the values as radians if I wanted, so consider that a non-issue. 

For the record, the Haversine formula I used I pulled from here http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: [The one on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) lists `d = 2 * r * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(h));`, so there's eliminating a call to `Math.Sqrt` which will help with performance right there. However, I think your overall design might have the greater issue. In a comment on the other question, you mention having to call `Haversine` 33,000 times per zip code for 500 zip codes (and thats where 16,500,000 comes from). First of all ***why***, and second of all, that kind of setup (assuming the zip codes are referencing each other) is just begging for using a look-up table.

Answer (score 10):

This was as optimized as I could get the answer (and, to my knowledge, this is the most optimized the answer could *possibly* get without doing some wizard-level optimization on the formula itself):

```cs
// inputs assumed to be in radians
private static double Haversine(double lat1, double lat2, double lon1, double lon2)
{
    const double r = 6378100; // meters
            
    var sdlat = Math.Sin((lat2 - lat1) / 2);
    var sdlon = Math.Sin((lon2 - lon1) / 2);
    var q = sdlat * sdlat + Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2) * sdlon * sdlon;
    var d = 2 * r * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(q));

    return d;
}
```

On my machine, this formula, when run 16.5 million times, runs at almost exactly 3 seconds, whereas the above version runs at just shy of 5.

However, I maintain that the biggest optimization could be in the system that actually calls this method. 33,000 times on each of 500 Latitude-Longitude pairs? That's a system that is likely in *dire* need of optimization itself. For starters, you could first calculate the linear-distance-squared of your pairs and only process pairs that are below a certain threshold. Or you could maintain a look-up table to avoid calculating the same pair more than once. Or, depending on the source of that 33,000 number, you can prioritize so that you don't need to call the method *nearly* that much.

Comment: Hey, I never said it was perfect :). Yeah, in this case I ended up going with the 10 nearest coordinate locations (by linear measurement), and then narrowing it down to 5 by calculating the Haversine distance, which cut the calculation time in half. I plan to change a lot before my use case is done, but I think the one thing that will stay the same is that I'll provide a coordinate, and return coordinates close to that one.

Comment: Comparing with GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo method results are very different, I think the Microsoft one is consistent.

Comment: In the old days using C++, multiplying by 0.5 is faster than dividing by 2. Does that speed up C# too?

Comment: @SimonHughes Theoretically yes, but it would be such a small performance gain that it would be completely insignificant. Looking at the results of this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yXgy6M), even running the comparison a billion times shows that the gain from using multiplication rather than division is a handful of milliseconds - so minor that it falls within the margin of error for benchmarking. There will always be other things in your program that would be better to optimize than trying to micromanage your program's arithmetic.

Comment: @SimonHughes Another thing that's entirely possible is that, in that last example, the C# compiler may have optimized the arithmetic out entirely, making it so the benchmarking is really just testing the performance of a single assignment. To get around this, you would need to use values that you get from a function that returns a dynamic value. The problem with _that_ approach is that the performance difference of the two arithmetic operations would be entirely eclipsed by the performance of the function that is generating the numbers.

Comment: @SimonHughes So the moral of the story is this: 99.99999% of the time, you should not be worrying about the performance of your arithmetic code because optimizing it would give such negligible gains as to not even be worth mentioning. And on the off-chance that you are in a position where you can conclusively say you have polished literally every other aspect of your code to a mirror shine and you still need those extra nanoseconds shaved off your program's runtime, then you are the kind of person who is knowledgable enough in code optimization voodoo to not have to ask this question.

Comment: This function (and OPs) seem to return nonsense results for the haversine function?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell How so? I will say that both this function and OP's function assume that the input coordinates are already expressed in radians.

Comment: Ohhh, that would be why.

Comment: Just a note, this function returns the distance in kilometres (as the radius of the earth is in km). I expected meters because of the comment

Comment: Is there a reason why this isn't using Math.Pow() for sdLong * sdLong and also for the sdLat in the equation for q?

Comment: @RobinDalmy Why would you use it? Multiplication can boil down to a simple CPU instruction, and while it's nowhere near as efficient as, say, addition, it's a well-solved problem. On the other hand, `Math.Pow` is a general-purpose function, and as such, it will add _massive_ overhead at minimum (some benchmarks put `Math.Pow(x, 2)` at anywhere from 10x to 100x slower than `x*x`), and while the compiler might be intelligent enough to convert it into multiplication anyway, in a highly performance-sensitive application like this one, it's best not to take the chances.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jYHsEV. Your distance is 338.200231772359m and in fact it is 6.2 meters. Results are ... insane at least.

Comment: @pregmatch you passed degrees; function expects radians. You'll need e.g. `Math.Sin(Math.PI * (lat2 - lat1) / 360.0)`

Comment: @Abion47 - Just the overhead of assembling the argument list for the call to Math.Pow() would take more code than the multiply instruction and the call/return time is probably longer than the multiply instruction.

Answer (score 6):

For me this is more accurate

```
public static class Haversine {
  public static double calculate(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    var R = 6372.8; // In kilometers
    var dLat = toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    var dLon = toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    lat1 = toRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = toRadians(lat2);

    var a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) + Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2);
    var c = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(a));
    return R * c;
  }

  public static double toRadians(double angle) {
    return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
  }
}

void Main() {
  Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The distance between coordinates {0},{1} and {2},{3} is: {4}", 36.12, -86.67, 33.94, -118.40, Haversine.calculate(36.12, -86.67, 33.94, -118.40)));
}

// Returns: The distance between coordinates 36.12,-86.67 and 33.94,-118.4 is: 2887.25995060711
```

Comment: I'm late in coming back to this, but this approach makes a critical mistake of calculating `Math.Sin(dLat / 2)` and `Math.Sin(dLon / 2)` twice each instead of calculating each once and caching the result. Arithmetic is cheap but trigonometric functions are expensive, so doing trig when it isn't necessary makes the algorithm not very efficient.